# Why is geom_text() plotting the text several times?

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-text

Please consider the following minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_text(x = 20, y = 20, label = "(20,20)")
```

[image: overplotted text]

I guess you can see pretty easily that the text "(20,20)" is heavily overplotted (actually, I don't know whether that's the correct word. I mean that the text is plotted several times at one location).

If I use `annotate()`, this does not happen:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
  geom_line() +
  annotate("text", x = 20, y = 20, label = "(20,20)")
```

[image: no overplotted text]

"So, why don't you use `annotate()` then?" you might ask. Actually, I don't want to use text for annotation but **labels**. And I also want to use the {ggrepel} package to avoid overplotting. But look what happens, when I try this:

```
ggplot(mtcars) +
  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_label_repel(x = 20, y = 20, label = "(20,20)")
```

[image: many many labels]

Again, many labels are plotted and {ggrepel} does a good job at preventing them from overlapping. But I want only **one** label pointing at a specific location. I really don't understand why this happens. I only supplied one value for `x`, `y` and `label` each. I also tried `data = NULL` and `inherit.aes = F` and putting the values into `aes()` within `geom_label_repel()` to no effect. I suspect that there are as many labels as there are rows in `mtcars`. For my real application that's really bad because I have a lot of rows in the respective dataset.

Could you help me out here and maybe give a short explanation why this happens and why your solution works? Thanks a lot!

Comment: `geom_text` adds `(20,20)` for each row in `mtcars`

Comment: Yeah, I suspected this. But why does this happen when I specified only one value for x, y, and label? And how do I resolve this in the geom_label_repel case?

Comment: You should pass different data for such annotation, for example: `geom_text(aes(20, 20, label = "(20,20)"), data.frame())` or `geom_label_repel(aes(20, 20, label = "(20,20)"), data.frame())`

Comment: Holy s..., this works! And also for the case of

ggplot(mtcars) +

  aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +

  geom_line() +

  geom_label_repel(aes(x = 20, y = 20, label = "(20,20)"), data.frame())

Comment: Thanks! If you want, write it up as an answer and I'll accept it. Still don't fully understand why `data = NULL` doesn't work.

Comment: In documentation it says that data is "A data frame. If specified, overrides the default data frame defined at the top level of the plot". NULL doesn't override it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`geom_text` or `geom_label_repel` adds one label per row. Therefore you can submit a separate dataset for annotation geom. For example:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggrepel)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, qsec)) +
    geom_line() +
    geom_label_repel(aes(20, 20, label = "(20,20)"), data.frame())
```

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Add "check_overlap = TRUE" to geom_text to prevent overplotting.

```
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(mtcars) +
        aes(x = mpg, y = qsec) +
        geom_line() +
        geom_text(x = 20, y = 20, label = "(20,20)", check_overlap = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Tjebo, it works, adding "check_overlap = TRUE" to geom_text, as shown above,  prevents overplotting.

Comment: My bad! I tested it yesterday using R online (me not being at home) and it somehow did not work. The downvote is not mine btw.